# When opening docx file using its presigned url present in gcs in google chrome file is downloaded instead of opening in new tab

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, python-docx

I want to generate presigned url for docx file present in gcs. I am able to generate it using blob.generate_signed_url method in python but when i open that presinged url link in chrome browser instead of opening file in new tab the file gets downloaded (file is open in new tab in microsoft edge browser). Can anyone help me to resolve this issue or give me any hint what can I do to open this docx file in new tab in google chrome browser?

here is the method i used to generate presigned url for docx file

```
url = blob.generate_signed_url(
        version="v4",
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
        service_account_info),
        response_disposition='inline',
        # This URL is valid for 120 seconds.
        expiration=120,
        # Allow GET requests using this URL.
        method="GET"
    )
```